# Optimising code for processing .docx files

Tags: ms-word, pywin32

I've recently tried out learning Python. I'm currently trying to make a project that can be used for my work. Basically, it iterates through the whole .docx file and check if each paragraph does not follow a specific format, and highlights it.

I have a kind of working solution, however, biggest concern is that it finishes running after 80 minutes which kind of defeats the purpose. Not sure what other else optimisations I can make or maybe if I missed something that could be used. Here is my code(replaced file name):

```
import win32com.client
import time

start_time = time.time()

word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word_app.Visible = True

doc = word_app.Documents.Open("test.docx")

def check_if_in_table(paragraph):
    return paragraph.Range.Tables.Count > 0

paragraphs = list(doc.Paragraphs)

outline_list = []
content = []

for paragraph in paragraphs:
    if not check_if_in_table(paragraph):
        outline_list.append(paragraph.OutlineLevel)
        content.append(paragraph.Range.Text)

outline_list = [paragraph.OutlineLevel for paragraph in paragraphs if not check_if_in_table(paragraph)]
content = [paragraph.Range.Text for paragraph in paragraphs if not check_if_in_table(paragraph)]

outline_list_length = len(outline_list) - 1

for i in range(outline_list_length):
    if outline_list[i] == 1:
        outline_list[i + 1] = 'chapter_bodytext'
    elif outline_list[i] == 'chapter_bodytext':
        if outline_list[i + 1] == 10 or i == len(outline_list) -2:
            outline_list[i + 1] = 'chapter_bodytext'
    elif outline_list[i] == 2:
        outline_list[i + 1] = 'subchapter_bodytext'
    elif outline_list[i] == 'subchapter_bodytext':
        if outline_list[i + 1] == 10 or i == len(outline_list) - 2:
            outline_list[i + 1] = 'subchapter_bodytext'
    elif outline_list[i] == 3:
        outline_list[i + 1] = 'section_bodytext'
    elif outline_list[i] == 'section_bodytext':
        if outline_list[i + 1] == 10 or i == len(outline_list) -2:
            outline_list[i + 1] = 'section_bodytext'

content_tuples = zip(outline_list, content)

for key, value in content_tuples:
    if key == 'chapter_bodytext' or key == 'subchapter_bodytext':
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            if paragraph.Range.Text == value:
                list_level = paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
                list_type = paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListType
                left_indent = paragraph.LeftIndent
                right_indent = paragraph.RightIndent
                
                if list_level == 1:
                    if list_type == 0 and (left_indent != 0 or right_indent != 0):
                        paragraph.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 7
                    elif list_type != 0 and (left_indent != 0.25 * 72 or right_indent != 0):
                        paragraph.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 7
                elif list_level == 2 and (left_indent != 0.75 * 72 or right_indent != 0):
                    paragraph.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 7
                elif list_level == 3 and (left_indent != 1.25 * 72 or right_indent != 0):
                    paragraph.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 7
                elif list_level == 4 and (left_indent != 1.75 * 72 or right_indent != 0):
                    paragraph.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 7

doc.SaveAs("test.docx")
doc.Close()

end_time = time.time()
print(f'Complete, took {(end_time - start_time)/60} minutes')
```

The for i in range(outline_list_length) loop is needed because it needs to know which body text are under a specific outline level. I have been looking for a way if there is a method in pywin32 to know if a body text is collapsible under a certain outline level (1, 2 or 3) but I haven't found a way.

What other things can I do to optimise this? Will appreciate any advise or suggestions!